# Gray circle next to large notification icon?

Tags: android, android-notifications, android-notification-bar, android-icons

Im displaying notifications in my app - but for some reason on android version `Lolipop` its displaying a gray circle next to the large icon like this:

[image]

Does anyone have an idea why is this happening?

Here is my code in which I create my notifications:

```
builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                    // Set Icon
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                    .setLargeIcon(icon)
                    // Set Ticker Message
                    .setTicker(message)
                    // Set Title
                    .setContentTitle(message)
                    // Set Text
                    .setContentText(context.getString(R.string.app_name))
                    // Add an Action Button below Notification
                    // .addAction(R.drawable.share,
                    // context.getString(R.string.share), pendingShare)
                    // Set PendingIntent into Notification
                    .setContentIntent(contentIntent)
                    // Dismiss Notification
                    .setAutoCancel(true)
                    .setSound(
                            Uri.parse("android.resource://"
                                    + context.getPackageName()
                                    + "/"
                                    + prefs.getInt(Constants.NOTIF_SOUND,
                                            R.raw.al_affassi_full)));
```

Comment: I think that is small icon which you set. Try after commenting `setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)`

Comment: @PankajKumar that way notification makes sound but no notifications is displayed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your notification icon must follow the notification design from here : [iconography notifications](http://developer.android.com/design/style/iconography.html#notification)

> Notification icons must be entirely white. Also, the system may scale down and/or darken the icons.

**Edit**

try with this image (the image is white and is between the ///)

///
[image: small icon]
///

Comment: I've made my small icon white and 16x16px but same issue, circle stands nor displays come icon inside of it

Comment: Can you share with me your white small icon please

Comment: It is not only white, please remove the blue color and make it only white with transparent background

Comment: Ok ill try, but I dont think this is this issue here

Comment: You can use this to make a notification icon (probably unrelated to the question but still worth having a look at): http://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/icons-notification.html#source.space.trim=1&source.space.pad=0&name=ic_stat_example